# Using Platform.runLater to change button text in non javafx thread

Tags: java, javafx

I`m trying to update button text from non javafx thread using Platform.runLater but text doesn't change

Code:

```
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("GUI.fxml"));
    Parent root = loader.load();
    Map<String, Object> namespace = loader.getNamespace();

    Button button = (Button) namespace.get("pc");

    System.out.println("before " + button);
    Platform.runLater(() -> button.setText("test2"));
    System.out.println("after " + button);
```

Log:

```
before Button[id=pc, styleClass=button]'test1'
after Button[id=pc, styleClass=button]'test1'
```

Answer (score 5):

A call to `Platform.runLater` does not wait for the `Runnable` to complete before returning. From the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater(java.lang.Runnable)) (**emphasis** mine):

> Run the specified Runnable on the JavaFX Application Thread at **some unspecified time in the future**. This method, which may be called from any thread, will post the Runnable to an event queue and **then return immediately to the caller**. The Runnables are executed in the order they are posted. A runnable passed into the runLater method will be executed before any Runnable passed into a subsequent call to runLater. If this method is called after the JavaFX runtime has been shutdown, the call will be ignored: the Runnable will not be executed and no exception will be thrown.
>
> ...

This means there's no guarantee the `Button`'s text has been updated by the time the following is invoked:

```
System.out.println("after " + button);
```

Note that if all this took place on the *JavaFX Application Thread* you still wouldn't see the change. This is because the FX thread wouldn't have had a chance to process the `Runnable` yet, which would still be sitting in the event queue.

---

Additionally, you aren't establishing a *happens-before* relationship between the FX thread writing to the `text` property and the background thread reading from the `text` property. Even if the FX thread managed to set the property before you attempt to print it to `System.out` there's no guarantee your background thread would see the new value.

Comment: I moved both println to Platform.runLater lambda and i got output: `before Button[id=pc, styleClass=button]'test1'` `after Button[id=pc, styleClass=button]'test2'` but nothing has changed in GUI

Comment: That sounds like a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (don't forget a [mre]).